# Restricting AWS Secrect for Single AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Experts,

I am using AWS Api gateways as a proxy over AWS Lambda for my client calls. API Gateway has a timeout of 29000 milliseconds which is becoming an issue for one of our Lambda call requires around 2 minutes to complete.

Memory is not an issue - the operation is a bit time consuming.

One of the dirty but quickest ways to solve this issue to call the lambda directly from the client app skipping the AWS API gateway however I have to then hardcode the access key and secret in the client app.

As we are struggling with this issue on production the quickest and dirty solution seems to be the way forward for now and then later on replaced with WebSockets.

Still, to avoid major security issue I was thinking about whether can we restrict the access key and secret to only 1 lambda function

Comment: If you are ok with async invokation I would recommend reworking your architecture instead. API GW -> SQS -> Lambda.

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: Yes, you could limit the IAM credentials to only invoking that Lambda function. Alternatively, the app could authenticate use an Unauthenticated Access Pool with Amazon Cognito to obtain temporary credentials to call the Lambda function.

Comment: Setup SQS integration with API Gateway, so when you make a POST request it puts the payload to a queue, that queue starts a lambda. Downside is that your client will not know whether/when the task was finished. If you need that you could implement an endpoint with the state of the previous job and then poll it from the client.